# chef specify openjdk package on ubuntu

Tags: java, chef, packages, vagrant

I'm creating a Vagrantfile that uses chef solo to install OpenJDK on Ubuntu 12.04. Is there a way to specify which specific package of OpenJDK is installed? This way I can be sure I'm consistent across multiple installs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the exact version number of a package as an attribute inside the `package` resource:

```
package "foo" do
  action :install
  version "1.2.3"
end
```

If the version number expected is not present in an available apt repository the recipe will fail with an exception.